# Uncheck checkbox by id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, prop

**Code :**

```
$(function() {

$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "click", function() {
deptsSelected = '<div id = "selected_'+this.id+'">  '+ $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text() + '<span id="delete">X</span></div>';
        $("#tabs").append(deptsSelected); 

});



    $(document).on("click", "#delete", function(e) { 
            id = $(this).parent().attr('id')
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).parent().remove();  
            var checkid = $("#"+id.slice(9));
            checkid.prop("checked", false);
  });
```

The code above should uncheck the specific Checkbox when the user clicks on the specific Div. The Div is dynamically generated by JQuery, so what I have done here is to take the id of the new generated Div and use slice function to take the id of the checkbox that I want to uncheck.
 How can I uncheck the box that I want by using id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to put prefix `#` for id   or `.` for class

Suppose it is id

```
 var checkid = $('#' + id.slice(9));
 checkid.prop("checked", false);
```

or class use like

```
var checkid = $('.' + id.slice(9));
checkid.prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ID prefix:

```
var checkid = $('#' + id.slice(9));
```

Change this part:

```
var checkid = $(id.slice(9));
```

Answer (score 1):

here we go:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "click", function() {
deptsSelected = '<span id="delete" data-checkbox="'+this.id+'">X</span></div>';
        $("#tabs").append(deptsSelected); 
});

    $(document).on("click", "#delete", function(e) { 
            var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            var checkboxID = $(this).attr('data-checkbox');
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).remove();
            $('#'+checkboxID).attr('checked', false);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uure20xe/

Answer (score 1):

Here what I have done :

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "click", function() {
    deptsSelected = '<div id = "selected_'+this.id+'">  '+ $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text() + '<span class="delete">X</span></div>';
    $("#tabs").append(deptsSelected); 

});

$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(e) { 
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var id = parent.attr('id')
    parent.remove();  
    var checkid = $('#'+id.replace("selected_", ""));
    checkid.prop("checked", false);
});
```

Your code still have some problem like : if I uncheck myself the checkbox, it is appending the div, but this is not the problem in your question.

Here a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/te8jp09d/)